# Is this a memory leak ? Node.js handlebars partials

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

[heap snapshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1POf2.png)

I run garbage collector before each snapshot.
while testing with **ab** it seems like memory usage increasing by 5mb / 100 requests and do not decrease after running GC

looks like a leak caused by handlebars partials.
what do you think ? how can i solve this ?

**Update**

```
const handlebars = require("express-handlebars"); 
const cond = require("handlebars-cond").cond; 
const dateFormat = require("handlebars-dateformat"); 
app.engine('.hbs', handlebars({ defaultLayout: null, extname: '.hbs', helpers: { cond, dateFormat   } })).set("view engine", "hbs");
```

*the route handler*

```
module.exports.allEmployees = (req, res, next) => {
    let startTime = new Date();
    Employee.findAllAndPopulateImage()
        .then(employees =>{     
            // printEmployees(employees);
            playSoundIfVolumeOn(req, "List of employees");
            winston.info("Treatment time : " + (new Date() - startTime));
            return res.render("employees", { employees });
        }).catch(handleError(next));
}
```

Comment: You should share the code you suspect has the memory leak. Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: `   const handlebars = require("express-handlebars");
   const cond = require("handlebars-cond").cond;
   const dateFormat = require("handlebars-dateformat");
   app.engine('.hbs', handlebars({ 
    defaultLayout: null, extname: '.hbs' ,
    helpers: { cond, dateFormat }
   })).set("view engine", "hbs");`

Comment: Can you edit the question and add it there? Should be easier to read than if it's stuffed in a comment. Also, you probably have some routes that `ab` is exercising. Seeing what the route does will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is caused by the express-handlebars dependency

        `return res.send({ employees });
        //return res.render("employees", { employees });`

I changed this line and the heavy string objects are gone.

[heap snapshots 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2k4T.png)

**Update**
It's actually caused by the node inspector
https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3751#issuecomment-424077960

I also made a verification after a 1000 request and the memory is freed succesfully
[memoryUsage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eABf.png)